# What the the variables in following program stores?

Tags: list, recursion, count, prolog

```
total_item([],0).
total_item([_|Rest],N) :- total_item(Rest,C), N is C+1.
```

This program takes an array as input and count the total number of item in that list. But I am not getting what exactly variable N and C stores. Any explanation would be appreciate. Thank you

Comment: I would recommend you try running it with trace and watch as Prolog calculates the answer. [Here is an online copy of your program I've made](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/lama-madan-trace-variable-values.pl), just run `trace, total_item([1,2,3,4,5], X).` in the query box.

Answer (score 2):

Read it backwards:

```
total_item([], 0).
```

`total_item` maps `0` to `[]` (*relates* the two).

```
total_item([_ | Rest], N) :- 
    total_item( Rest,       C    ), 
                       N is C + 1 .
```

with `C` mapped to `Rest`, `C+1` is mapped to `[_ | Rest]` -- the list one element longer than the list `Rest`.

See this with the most general query working in the generative fashion:

```
2 ?- total_item(L, C).
L = [],
C = 0 ;
L = [_G1464],
C = 1 ;
L = [_G1464, _G1467],
C = 2 ;
L = [_G1464, _G1467, _G1470],
C = 3 ;
L = [_G1464, _G1467, _G1470, _G1473],
C = 4 .
```

Answer (score 2):

Will Ness answer should have provided you with a clear understanding of that predicate definition. But there's more that you can learn from it. Let's do a trace of a simple call. Here I'm using GNU Prolog but most Prolog system provide the same trace functionality:

```
| ?- trace.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)

yes
{trace}
| ?- total_item([1,2,3], N).
      1    1  Call: total_item([1,2,3],_285) ? 
      2    2  Call: total_item([2,3],_354) ? 
      3    3  Call: total_item([3],_378) ? 
      4    4  Call: total_item([],_402) ? 
      4    4  Exit: total_item([],0) ? 
      5    4  Call: _430 is 0+1 ? 
      5    4  Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
      3    3  Exit: total_item([3],1) ? 
      6    3  Call: _459 is 1+1 ? 
      6    3  Exit: 2 is 1+1 ? 
      2    2  Exit: total_item([2,3],2) ? 
      7    2  Call: _285 is 2+1 ? 
      7    2  Exit: 3 is 2+1 ? 
      1    1  Exit: total_item([1,2,3],3) ? 

N = 3

(1 ms) yes
```

You can see in the first four lines that the predicate results in walking the list until the end and *only then* we compute the *pending* `N is C + 1` goals. Each element in the list results in one pending arithmetic evaluation goal. These pending goals must be stored in a *stack* until the recursive call to the `total_item /2` predicate terminates. As a consequence, computing the length of a list of size N requires space (for the stack) proportional to N. I.e. this predicate definition is not *tail-recursive*.

But we can rewrite the predicate, making it *tail-recursive* to improve its space complexity by using an *accumulator*. An accumulator is an argument that stores intermediate results, in this case, the count so far of the number of elements in the list:

```
total_item(List, Total) :-
    total_item(List, 0, Total).

total_item([], Total, Total).
total_item([_| Rest], Total0, Total) :-
    Total1 is Total0 + 1,
    total_item(Rest, Total1, Total).
```

Let's trace the same goal:

```
| ?- total_item([1,2,3], N).
      1    1  Call: total_item([1,2,3],_285) ? 
      2    2  Call: total_item([1,2,3],0,_285) ? 
      3    3  Call: _382 is 0+1 ? 
      3    3  Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
      4    3  Call: total_item([2,3],1,_285) ? 
      5    4  Call: _435 is 1+1 ? 
      5    4  Exit: 2 is 1+1 ? 
      6    4  Call: total_item([3],2,_285) ? 
      7    5  Call: _488 is 2+1 ? 
      7    5  Exit: 3 is 2+1 ? 
      8    5  Call: total_item([],3,_285) ? 
      8    5  Exit: total_item([],3,3) ? 
      6    4  Exit: total_item([3],2,3) ? 
      4    3  Exit: total_item([2,3],1,3) ? 
      2    2  Exit: total_item([1,2,3],0,3) ? 
      1    1  Exit: total_item([1,2,3],3) ? 

N = 3

(1 ms) yes
```

Notice that how the accumulator, the second argument in the auxiliary `total_item/3` predicate is incremented as we walk thew list. With this definition, there are no pending goals, which means the space complexity is O(1) instead of O(N). Much better.