# Correct use of is/2 predicate in Prolog recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog, declarative, instantiation-error

I am a Prolog beginner with an imperative programming background. While solving assignments from [this site](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/), I bumped into two exercises: the first one regards **finding the k-th elements of a list**, the second one is about **finding a list's length**. Those are classical list-processing problems with a pretty straightforward solution, also for a beginner like me. What I was unable to understand was the (apparently) different use of the built-in `is/2` predicate. As far as I am concerned, this predicate forces Prolog to carry on an arithmetic calculation and possibly assign the result to the left-hand side term. What I was told to be aware of is that, *although it's possible to use variables in the right-hand side, those have to be instantiated with a variable-free term at the moment of evaluation*.

For the first exercise the proposed solution is the following:

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :- K > 1, K1 is K - 1, element_at(X,L,K1).
```

and the way `is` is used makes sense to me: since `K` is provided as an argument, `K1` can be immediately evaluated and supplied as a new argument in the recursive call.

By writing a solution to the second exercise, namely finding a list length, I came up with the following:

```
my_length([], 0).
my_length([_|L], K) :- K is K1 + 1, my_length(L, K1).
```

and was notified by Prolog that *"arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"*. 
The correct solution turned out to be this one:

```
my_length([], 0).
my_length([_|L], K) :- my_length(L, K1), K is K1 + 1.
```

In this case, the recursive call is made **before** evaluating K by means of `is`. In the previous exercise, it was made **after** evaluating `K is K-1`.

I think I misunderstood some key concepts. What are the cases in which `is/2` has to be used before the recursive call and, on the other hand, when has it to be used after? Why is it so?
Any help and explanation is appreciated (I am using SWI-Prolog 7.6.4).

Comment: As you're defining your own list length predicates, you likely shouldn't be calling the Prolog system `length/2` predicates in your definitions...

Comment: See also the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994448/what-the-the-variables-in-following-program-stores/51994904#51994904

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, will edit now

Comment: In your examples did you meant to say `K is K1 + 1` instead of `K1 is K + 1` ?? (K is the length of [_|L], K1 is the length of L, so K>K1, K1 is K +1 doesn't makes sense...)

Comment: @PauloMoura I checked the question you linked and it was a good contribution for clarifying my doubts. If you mind to put it as an answer, I will accept it gladly (otherwise I will do it by myself for future reference).

Comment: @kernel_panic You can always vote that other question and answers and edit/update your question with a link to it. Repeating those two answers here doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` should only be used when all the variables in its right-hand side term are already instantiated. You say as much yourself. So, in your `at` predicate, it is designed so that `K` *must* already be instantiated to a numerical expression when the predicate is called in a query -- i.e., any other query will cause an error. Since `K` is already instantiated, it's OK to call `is`.

In the second predicate, `K` is the *output* you're expecting (as well as, possibly, an input to be validated). Since it is *not* guaranteed to be known when the call is made, such a query must be allowed to work. This means, `K` mustn't be assumed to be known. And if it's unknown, `is` can't be called at that time, otherwise it will cause an error.

Thus we make the recursive call first, as it will surely instantiate `K`, if it weren't already.